# I can't interact with my CollectionView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to interact with the cells in my CollectionView, but I can't get anything to work.

At first, I was just trying to print something to the logs by clicking on the cell. That didn't work. I did this by declaring a "didSelectItemAt" function.

Next I added a button to the cell, and added an IBAction to print something to the log, but that doesn't work either.

I tried adding `collectionview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true` to the viewDidLoad() method, that didn't work. I also checked the storyboard

I'm adding the datasource and delegate by doing

```
collectionview.delegate = self
collectionview.dataSource = self
```

I also tried adding a UITapGestureRecognizer in viewDidLoad, but that just made my app crash when loading the view.

I can interact with other collectionviews, but I just can't interact with this collection view. I'm not sure if scrolling works because I only have one cell loading in this collection view so far.

Anybody have any ideas on what I can do or how to correctly implement UITapGestureRecognizer?

Here is the full code for the CollectionView:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseUI


class UserViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionview: UICollectionView!

    var user = [User]()
    var following = [String]()

    var userStorage: StorageReference!
    var ref : DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionview.delegate = self
        collectionview.dataSource = self

        collectionview.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
//        self.collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "UserCell")

        retrieveUsers()
//        let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIInputViewController.dismissKeyboard))
//        tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
//        collectionview.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    @IBAction func buttonPress(_sender: Any){
        print("fuck you")
    }


    func retrieveUsers() {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        let uids = Database.database().reference().child("users")
        uids.observeSingleEvent(of:.value, with:{
            (snapshot) in
                    let users = snapshot.value as! [String : NSDictionary]
                        //self.user.removeAll()
                        for (_, value) in users {

                            if let uid = value["uid"] as? String {
                                if uid != Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid {
                                    let userToShow = User()
                                    if let username = value["username"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String{

                                        userToShow.username = username
                                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                                        userToShow.userID = uid
                                        self.user.append(userToShow)
                                        print(userToShow)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        self.collectionview.reloadData()
                    })
                    //ref.removeAllObservers()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
           return user.count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {


        let cell = collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "userCell", for: indexPath) as! UserCell



          cell.userImage.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath))

           cell.nameLabel.text = self.user[indexPath.row].username
           cell.userID = self.user[indexPath.row].userID
//        let destinationVC = ProfileViewController()
//        destinationVC.sentUserID = user[indexPath.row].userID!

        // Let's assume that the segue name is called playerSegue
        // This will perform the segue and pre-load the variable for you to use
        //destinationVC.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileFromSearch", sender: self)


//        cell.addButtonTapAction = {
//            // implement your logic here, e.g. call preformSegue()
//            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "toProfileFromSearch", sender: self)
//        }
        //cell.userImage.downloadImage(from: self.user[indexPath.row].imagePath!)
        //checkFollowing(indexPath: indexPath)


        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("hello world")
//        let VC1 = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController") as! ProfileViewController
//        VC1.sentUserID = user[indexPath.row].userID
//        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC1, animated: true)
    }












    func checkFollowing(indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let ref = Database.database().reference()

        ref.child("users").child(uid).child("following").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

            if let following = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                for (_, value) in following {
                    if value as! String == self.user[indexPath.row].userID {
//                        self.tableview.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark
                    }
                }
            }
        })
        ref.removeAllObservers()

    }

    @IBAction func logOutPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey:"uid")

        do{
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError{
            print("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


extension UIImageView {

    func downloadImage(from imgURL: String!) {
        let url = URLRequest(url: URL(string: imgURL)!)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) {
            (data, response, error) in

            if error != nil {
                print(error!)
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: What is a flow layout? What would I need to add to conform to UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout?

Comment: Did you check collection View selection? Is it selected single selection, check out your content(cell) UI  any button and Uiview not overlapped them.

Comment: @SukhwinderSingh the navigation bar slightly overlaps the cell. Would that be a problem?

Comment: @SukhwinderSingh I added a second user that doesn't overlap with the search bar at all and the didSelectItemAt function does not work. How do I get user interaction in a cell like many popular apps?

Comment: collectionView.allowsSelection = true

Comment: @K4747Z collectionView.allowsSelection = true still doesn't make didSelectItemAt() work. I don't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: What is your `UserCell` like? Does it have any buttons or gesture recognizers on it that could be eating up the touch?

Comment: There are no buttons or gesture recognizers. Just an IBOutlet for image and username and then a variable for userID.

Comment: @NickSteen check it with "Debug View hierarchy", this will shows you any interface are not overlapping them, if it is not working, last I has suggestion for you, remove collectionView and create new one. sometimes it has worked for me.